# auto increment and uniqueness issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having problem implementing auto-increment logic in my app. Says I inserts a 'group', and in mysql it has value 10 for its Id, next one would be 11, 12 and so forth.

But once the record (assume it's Id 12) got deleted, the next new item is 12 again. So it may have conflict.

Could possibly makes the auto increment don't repeat the same Int? I want every Id be unique, once it's delete means it never come back.

Comment: "*the next new item is 12 again*" - no it's not. Once a value has been used, it will not be generated again (and even if it did: as the old PK value 12 is gone, there is no harm in using it again).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you are wrong, InnoDB loses its maximal auto_increment during every start.

Comment: @flaschenpost: if that was true then MySQL would be pretty much unusable.

Comment: I just checked it, it at least holds for version 5.5.32-log. Remember: only after restart of the server. See my answer

Comment: @user3522457: please try out if this problem occurs only after shutdown and restart of the server and adjust the question according to that. I think it is worth a place in Wiki (if I could find out if there is already a question like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you not set id is primary key and auto increment

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB really has this "Feature" or Bug, that the recent auto_increment is NOT stored in the table space. As soon as you restart the MySQL Server, the "auto_increment" value is taken from the highest recent value of the table, thus conflicting with possibly deleted values.

The solution to this is really ugly. You could create a table with the highest unused values per table, in the form

```
tablename   maxvalue
 tableA      375
 tableB      12
```

and you could write a Post-Startup-Script, if you manage the MySQL-Server. So after every delete of a row of such a table you would check per AFTER DELETE, if that row was the max-value. That is a bit easier with newer versions of MySQL, since table informations are stored in INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and not only calculated with every select (which means reading INFORMATION_SCHEMA does not fire heavy and blocking queries so often).

You only have to update maxvalue if the deleted row was that max value.

It is a bit easier to update the maxalue on every insert on a row, if that does not slow down the system.

In some cases you have just one table with critical references, and that table has an index, so you can retrieve maxvalue from that table.

All in all that is a big problem with InnoDB, and writing a lot of Triggers just for this single unsaved number auto_increment is really not nice.

Comment: I can't believe there is no perfect solution for this. so AI is evil in my case?

Comment: Maybe you could try MariaDB, they are more like MyISAM. Or you stay at MyISAM without transactions. Or you do it like in Oracle where Sequences are defined (I don't know about that, I think it is like a table with only a column auto_increment).